# I want to display the ID of clicked Item in a class and delete it if clicked again

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an interface where you can select tickets and buy them, I want that when I click on a seat it displays like "You are currently buying the next tickets + (The tickets chosen by the user)".

This is my code so far:

```js
var seatsUnclicked = document.getElementsByClassName("seat-unique");
var seatsClicked = document.getElementsByClassName("seatClicked");
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
var seatsOutput = document.getElementsById("seatsOutput");
var ticketsData = 0
for (let i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++) {
  seatsUnclicked[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.src = "chairclicked.svg";
    this.onmouseout = function() {
      this.src = "chair.svg"
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('seatClicked')) {
      this.src = "chairclicked.svg";
      this.onmouseout = function() {
        this.src = "chairclicked.svg"
      }
    }
  }

  seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.add("new")

    if ($(this).hasClass('seatClicked')) {
      this.classList.remove("seatClicked")
      this.classList.remove("new")
      this.src = "chair.svg";
      this.onmouseout = function() {
        this.src = "chair.svg"
      }
      ticketsData = ticketsData - /* "the id of this element in a string" */
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('new')) {
      this.src = "chairclicked.svg";
      this.classList.add("seatClicked")
      this.classList.remove("new")
      this.onmouseout = function() {
        this.src = "chairclicked.svg"
      }
      ticketsData = ticketsData + /* "the ID of this element in a string" */
    }

    seatsOutput.innerHTML = "THE TICKETS YOU HAVE CHOSEN ARE" + string(ticketsData)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="seats-row-A">
  <img id="A1" class="seat-unique " src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=A1">
  <img id="A2" class="seat-unique " src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=A2">
  <img id="A3" class="seat-unique " src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=A3">
  <img id="A4" class="seat-unique " src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=A4">
  <img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=A5">
  <img id="A6" class="seat-unique " src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=A6">
  <img id="A7" class="seat-unique " src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=A7">
</div>
<h2 id="seatsOutput">Chosen Tickets:</h2>
```

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`?

Comment: I think I am not, but I could use it, would that make the job easier? sorry  I am new at this

Comment: I just asked because I saw that you're using some jQuery functions. Also, I didn't understand what your code is supposed to do? Why are you using mouseover and mouseout events?

Comment: Right now what the code does is when I click on a seat it changes the image to the same image but with different color, The mouseout is for a hover of the seat like when you put the mouse close to the element it changes the color of the seat and when you stop hovering it it puts back the old color, and now I am trying to make that when I choose each image I want to display to the user which seat Id he is choosing.. Well in that case I think I am using JQuery haha...

Answer (score 1):

### <del>jQuery</del>

---

The only jQuery statement in OP code is: `$(this).hasClass('seatClicked')`.

The plain JavaScript equivalent is: `this.classList.contains('seatClicked')`.

---

### Question

---

I couldn't follow the OP code because there was only a class, an id, and img tags that match the JavaScript, but it's not that clear because of the *.svg files (not provided.) Also, there's a curly bracket `}` missing (I think it belongs to the for loop, but I'm not wasting time on debugging typos.)

The Demo was built in mind with what the question and comments had mentioned:

- > *"...I want that when I click on a seat it displays like "You are currently buying..."*
- Highlight icon when hovered over.
- Reveal icon's id when hovered on.

All hover behavior is done with CSS: [`:hover`](http://www.developerdrive.com/2015/01/8-simple-css-hover-effects/), [`::before`, `::after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/), [`content: attr(id)`, `content: '\a0\1f4ba'`](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/). Using JavaScript for behavior CSS can do will result in more CPU cycles. CSS will use GPU of your graphics card instead of the CPU.

---

#### Testing

The seats are dynamically generated with `id="A*` by entering a number in the input and clicking the <kbd>View</kbd> button. For each additional click of the button a new batch of seats are appended and have ids that correspond to it's group:

```
input: 55 and first click A0-A55,
input: 12 and second click B0-B12,
input: 222 and third click C0-C222
...
Last group is J
```

---

### References

---

The Demo is basically a `<form>`. [**HTMLFormControlsCollection API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) is used to set/get *[form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Form-associated_content)* and values.

Reference the  tag

```
const ui = document.forms.tickets;
```

This is a collection of all form controls in form#tickets

```
const t = ui.elements;
```

Now all form controls are now accessible by prefixing a form control's #id or [name] with the HTMLFormControlsCollection Object.

```
<textarea name='textA'></textarea>
```

Without HFCC API

```
var ta = document.querySelector('[name=textA]');
```

With HFCC API

```
var ta = t.textA;
```

---

The links are collected by **[Links Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)**.

```
document.links
```

---

**[DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)** is used to insert a huge amount of dynamic HTML in one shot efficiently and quickly.

```
document.createDocumentFragment();
```

---

Various array methods were used:

- [**Array.from()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [**fill()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)
- [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

---

### Demo

---

```js
const ui = document.forms.tickets;
const t = ui.elements;
const seats = document.getElementById('seats');

t.btn.addEventListener('click', seatsAvailable);

seats.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let picked = [];
  pickSeat(e, picked);
}, false);


function pickSeat(e, picked) {
  const display = t.display;
  if (e.target.tagName === "A") {
    e.target.classList.toggle('picked');
    picked = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.picked'));
  }
  picked = picked.map(function(seat, index, picked) {
    return seat.id;
  });
  display.value = "";
  display.value = picked;
}

function seatsAvailable(e) {
  const qty = this.previousElementSibling;
  const last = document.links[document.links.length - 1].id;
  console.log(last);
  const limit = parseInt(qty.value, 10) + 1;
  const spots = new Array(limit);
  spots.fill(0, 0, limit);
  return generateSeats(spots, last);
}

function generateSeats(spots, last) {
  if (last.charAt(0) === "J") {
    t.display.textContent += "Last row available";
    return false;
  }
  const rowID = ['x', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
  let row = rowID.indexOf(last.charAt(0)) + 1;

  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const avSeats = spots.map(function(A, idx) {
    const seat = document.createElement('a');
    seat.id = rowID[row] + idx;
    seat.href = "#/";
    frag.appendChild(seat);
    return seat;
  });
  seats.appendChild(frag);
  if (document.links[0].id === 'x') {
    const x = document.getElementById('x');
    x.parentElement.removeChild(x);
  }
  if (document.links.length > 114) {
    const ext = (Math.round(document.links.length / 114)*600)+600;
    seats.style.maxHeight = ext+'px';
  }
  return avSeats;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  font: 400 16px/1.3 Consolas;
}

#seats {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: auto;
  border: 3px ridge grey;
}

.box {
  display: table
}

input,
button,
label {
  font: inherit
}

#qty {
  text-align: right
}

#display {
  display: table-cell;
}

.tag {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.3
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #2468ac;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #2468ac;
}

a::before {
  content: attr(id);
  color: transparent;
}

a:hover::before {
  color: #2468ac;
}

a.picked::before {
  color: #000;
}

a::after {
  content: '\a0\1f4ba';
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#x {
  pointer-events: none
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 70%
}
```

```html
<form id='tickets'>

  <fieldset class='box'>
    <legend>Available Seats</legend>

    <fieldset class='box'>
      <input id='qty' type='number' min='0' max='50' value='1'> <button id='btn' type='button'>View</button>

      <label class='tag'>Current ticket purchases to seats: 
       <output id='display'></output>
     </label>

    </fieldset>

    <section id='seats'>
      <a id='x' href='#/'></a>
    </section>

  </fieldset>

</form>
```